# Is it possible to use picture taken from camera in expo go app, without gallery permissions?

Tags: react-native, permissions, expo, react-native-image-picker

I'm using `expo-image-picker`.
I want to use images taken from the camera when only camera permission is granted and gallery permission is denied.
I don't need the image to be saved in the phone's gallery.
Right now I'm getting this error `User rejected permissions`, when I call `ImagePicker` function `launchCameraAsync`, like this:

```
ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
 mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
 allowsEditing: !isIOS,
 quality: 0.2,
 aspect: [2, 3],
})
```

Comment: If you don't need the image to be saved in the phone's gallery, then what you will do with the taken photo?

Comment: @KamalHossain directly read it from the `Image URI` (which we get when the image is taken from a camera) and upload it to the server

Comment: did you checked [expo camera](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/) instead of **ImagePicker**

Comment: No, I haven't. Will take a look. thanks